# stop bound pandas index in time series

Tags: python, pandas, indexing, dataframe

I have a pandas dataframe that represents a time series of measures. The index is dates in miliseconds and they are in order. The dataframe looks like this

```
Out[51]: 
                                      host  info parameter units   value
time                                                                        
1462964269947  parapluie-13.rennes.grid5000.fr  None   cpu_idl     %  98.624
1462964269947  parapluie-13.rennes.grid5000.fr  None   cpu_usr     %   1.209
1462964269947  parapluie-13.rennes.grid5000.fr  None   cpu_sys     %   0.167
1462964269948  parapluie-13.rennes.grid5000.fr  None   cpu_hiq     %   0.000
1462964269948  parapluie-13.rennes.grid5000.fr  None  cpu_wait     %   0.000
1462964269961  parapluie-13.rennes.grid5000.fr  None   cpu_siq     %   0.000
```

I want to slice the dataframe from a start to an end value. However this values might or might not be in the index. Because of that I'm getting the following error:

```
In[54]: dfg2.loc[1462964269947:1462964269963]
```

> KeyError: 'stop bound [1462964269963] is not in the [index]'

Is there anyway of setting and index and then slicing a range of values even when they don't exist in the index?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
print (df.index > 1462964269947) & (df.index < 1462964269963) 
[False False False  True  True  True]

print df[(df.index > 1462964269947) & (df.index < 1462964269963)] 
                                          host  info parameter units  value
time                                                                       
1462964269948  parapluie-13.rennes.grid5000.fr  None   cpu_hiq     %    0.0
1462964269948  parapluie-13.rennes.grid5000.fr  None  cpu_wait     %    0.0
1462964269961  parapluie-13.rennes.grid5000.fr  None   cpu_siq     %    0.0
```

Comment: I see. I was trying slicing because I had some performance issues when time was not an index but a column in the dataframe. (df.time>start) & (df.time<end) was just too slow. Will performance improve if I do it with the index?

Comment: Yes, you are right. Unfortunately I have no other idea.

Comment: I did the slicing directly with an index in the mongo database from where I get the data. It is a valid answer anyways so I accept it